# В чем отличия .then((data) => {...}); от .then(data => {...});

Tags: javascript, promise

я учу JS и then в Promise мне не очень понятен.

Есть ли отличия этого кода:

```
dataTransfer.then(product => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(product);
    }, 2000);
});
```

и этого

```
dataTransfer.then((product) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(product);
    }, 2000);
});
```

Буду очень признателен за небольшое объяснение!

Comment: "В чем отличия" - ни в чем.

Comment: Нет разницы это одно и то же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Круглые скобки в стрелочных функциях используются для передачи аргументов - как и в обычных (`function(){}`):

```js
const someFunc = () => { return "Hello, world!"; } // 0 параметров
const anotherFunc = (a) => { return a * 2; } // 1 параметр
const andAnother = (a, b, c) => { return a + b * c; }  // 3 параметра
// И так далее - в круглых скобках можно написать всё то же,
// что и в круглых скобках в function(){}

const useES6 = (...args) => { return args; } // ES6 spread operator! (если вы о нем  знаете)
```

Вариант без скобок был сделан специально.
Он работает для функций **только с одним аргументом**:

```
const multiplyBy2 = a => { return a*2; } // Работает для одного аргумента

const notWorkingFunc = a, b => { return a+b; } // Не сработает для двух
const anotherNotWorking =  => { return 1; } // Тоже не сработает (да и выглядит странно)

const useES6 = ...args => { return args; } // ES6 spread operator тут не работает
```

В вашем случае, так как параметр у функции один, то разницы нет.
Надеюсь, поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Выражения стрелочных функций имеют более короткий синтаксис по сравнению с функциональными выражениями и лексически привязаны к значению `this` (но не привязаны к собственному `this`, `arguments`, `super`, или `new.target`). Выражение стрелочных функций не позволяют задавать имя, поэтому стрелочные функции анонимны, если их ни к чему не присвоить.

Подробнее [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
// Круглые скобки не обязательны для единственного параметра:
(singleParam) => { statements }
singleParam => { statements }
```

Comment: По идее первый абзац никак не относится к вопросу

Comment: Да, но что просто не писать нет разницы